# Где я могу скачать подходящее JDK

Tags: java

Нужно установить jdk на компьютер.
Столкнулся с несколькими проблемами:

1. На ПК стоит х32(86) бит. система.
2. С оракла скачать не могу, нужна длинная регистрация, к которой я - школьник, не готов.
   Может есть у кого то ссылочки на более "народные сайты" с возможностью закачки?
   JDK какой версии я могу скачать(пункт 1)?

Comment: А еще можно OpenJDK скачать и другие свободные реализации

Comment: Плюс, я не уверен, но далеко не во всех версиях есть 32х битные версии.
Раньше последний версии выходили с большой задержкой. А может и вообще уже перестали. Повидавшие уже виды версии можно скачаьт без проблем

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужен JDK версии 8.xxx (самая востребованная версия)
2. Посмотрите [сюда](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable) - портабельная версия JDK x32 - в т.ч. подходит для установки на компьютер без админовских прав